# Azure Runbook job getting restarted when run on Hybrid runbook worker group

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-automation, hybrid-runbook-worker

I have an automation account configured with a Hybrid Runbook Worker, suddenly all jobs are getting restarted after every 15 mins 3 times and eventually gets suspended with the error:

Job was suspended. For additional troubleshooting, check the Microsoft-SMA event logs on the computers in the Hybrid Runbook Worker Group that tried to run this job.

Any idea? what can be the issue

Comment: any update ? I got the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Which region is your Automation Account in ? Can you please check the Microsoft-SMA event log and see if you see any errors there.

Thanks,
Anirudh

Comment: Hi Anirudh, I checked the SMA logs and I don't see any errors there. Also, the event logs are not descriptive enough I see something similar to this post https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/c36f3061-4074-499d-84d3-8b1dfb1df9a4/hybrid-worked-stopped-working?forum=azureautomation. Also, one strange thing i noticed is the workspace ID mentioned in MMA agent. I don't see any workspace with that ID on Azure portal. In fact,if i replace it with the correct workspace ID there, it automatically changes back to the same ID which doesn't exist. 
Do you have any idea on this?